# Creating a list from 2 tables with conditions using only 1 statement

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 tables A and B as below :

```
 A                  B
Name              Name
Burger          Avocado
Beef              Crab
Potato.           Pizza
```

I want to create a list that returns the names in 2 tables that have length> 5 using only 1 statement.

My code :

```
    SELECT A.Name,B.Name
    INTO LIST
    FROM A,B
    WHERE LENGTH(A.Name)>5 AND LENGTH(B.Name)>5;
```

Error : undeclared variable LIST.

My question is how can I declare LIST but still use only 1 statement for this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `SELECT INTO`. If table LIST is already created, I think what you need is:

```
INSERT INTO LIST
SELECT Name FROM A WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
UNION
SELECT Name FROM B WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5;
```

If table LIST doesn't exist yet, you could do:

```
CREATE TABLE LIST
AS
SELECT Name FROM A WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
UNION
SELECT Name FROM B WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5;
```

Comment: Thanks Rabat. Is there anyway we can get the list in only 1 statement ? I think Create and Select are 2 statements. This question is from my exam which asks for the code in only 1 statement . Thanks

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT on data set selected by UNION` it isn't right way.

Comment: @Spoonfed If you only need a list and it doesn't need to be materialized into a table, just use the select portion of the query. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually UNION does DISTINCT by default. UNION ALL is the one that doesn't. I updated to simplify the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run this query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LIST
SELECT Name FROM A WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
UNION
SELECT Name FROM B WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
;
```

This query will create temporary table `LIST` out of result received from query.

In case you already have table `LIST` and you need insert data into table - run next query:

```
INSERT INTO LIST
SELECT Name FROM A WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
UNION
SELECT Name FROM B WHERE LENGTH(Name) > 5
;
```

**BTW**

> return the names in 2 tables that have length> 5

for this you have to use `UNION` otherwise your result will look like:

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Name
FROM A,B
WHERE LENGTH(A.Name)>5 AND LENGTH(B.Name)>5;
+--------+---------+
| Name   | Name    |
+--------+---------+
| Burger | Avocado |
| Potato | Avocado |
+--------+---------+
```

But it looks like you need something like:

```
select * from LIST;
+---------+
| Name    |
+---------+
| Burger  |
| Potato  |
| Avocado |
+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir ! Is there anyway we can return such a list in only 1 statement ? As my exam question asks for only 1 statement but it seems like Create and Select are 2 statements .

Comment: In case you already have table `LIST` you have to run `INSERT INTO LIST SELECT ...`, I've updated my answer so you can see whole query.